# CoreOS alternative to /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/

Tags: coreos

I recently stumbled across the fact that on shutdown/reboot any script in /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown will get executed before the shutdown starts.

Paraphrasing - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html

With the /usr filesystem being read only on CoreOS I cannot put any of my shutdown scripts in /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown.   I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable about CoreOS and systemd knows an alternate directory path on CoreOS nodes that would give me the same results.  Or a configuration that I can adjust to point the directory to /etc/systemd/system-shutdown or something else.

Optionally any pointers on creating a custom service that does the same thing as systemd-shutdown.

My use case is that I have a few scripts that I want to execute when a node shutsdown.  For example remove the node from the monitoring system, unschedule the node in kubernetes and drain any running pods while allowing in flight transactions to finish.